# Pickling Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, caching, orm, pickle

```
from myapp.models import MyModel
from cPickle import *

tmp = MyModel.objects.all()[:1]
print(loads(dumps(t, -1)) == t)
#Output is "False"
```

In my case pickled query result differs from unpickled. I already read here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets
that such operations are actually allowed. So - what am I doing wrong?

upd #1: Tried cPickle and regular Pickle - got 'False' from both

upd #2: Possible resolution - converting QuerySet to Python list with `list()`. Found it while reading these: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to compare two querysets and querysets doesn't have a `__cmp__` method defined.

So, you can compare a queryset with itself and you will get this:

```
>> tmp == tmp
True
```

This is because, as there are no `__cmp__` method, `==` evaluates `True` if both objects have the same identity (the same memory address). You can read it from [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)

So, when you do this:

```
>> loads(dumps(tmp, -1)) == tmp
False
```

you will get a `False` as a result because objects have different memory addresses. If you convert queries into a "comparable" object, you can get the behaviour you want. Try with this:

```
>> set(loads(dumps(tmp, -1))) == set(tmp)
True
```

Hope it helps!